# Compare excel sheets in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have two Excel files contains the following structure,

EmployeeAllDtl.xlsx

```
id  email   name    age dept
```

EmployeeEmail.xlsx

```
email address_id
```

Now I need to compare the two files based on 'email'. So the out put files will be 
ExcelFound.xlsx - Contains all the found in both files

ExcelNotFound.xlsx - Contains all records which are in EmployeeAllDtl.xlsx but not on EmployeeEmail.xlsx.

Both files will be in the structure of **EmployeeAllDtl.xlsx**

How can I create the output using C# and SQL Server 2008 ?

Comment: Why do you mention SQL Server?

Comment: @Mikey Cee  See the answer by Chris Kelly. Yes, that is why I did mention SQL Server. We can do it without writing a single line of C# code.

Comment: Cool, I never knew you could do that!

Comment: @Mikey Cee  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2008 you can do this without writing a single line of C#. Use the [Import and Export wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) in SSMS to get the data into a SQL Server database. Once the data is in MSSQL, SELECT INTO a new table the rows from one with no match in the other. Finally, use the Import and Export wizard again to create the XLSX output.

There is an option in the wizard to save the SSIS package that it generates. If you need to perform this comparison multiple times you can save the packages and set up a SQL Agent job to do all 3 steps. If you know or wish to learn SSIS you could create a single package to do all the work.